# How to find which winforms object has been selected and execute conditionals based on response

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that contains a large number of methods.
Class contains methods such as

```
private void letterLogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Do something
}

private void letterLogToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Do something
}
```

I want to design a single function that handle both requests depending on which one is executed.

How can I tell the function which option was selected

i.e

```
if (foobar == letterLogToolStripMenuItem_Click)
{
 Do something
}

else if(foobar == private void letterLogToolStripMenuItem2
{
 Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must assign click events of these controls to same event.

```
letterLogToolStripMenuItem.Click += LetterLogToolStripMenuItem_Click;
letterLogToolStripMenuItem2.Click += LetterLogToolStripMenuItem_Click;
```

Now, both of the buttons will run the same function when clicked. Then you can determine which is the sender of the event.

```
 private void LetterLogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == letterLogToolStripMenuItem)
            {
             //letterLogToolStripMenuItem clicked
            }
            if (sender == letterLogToolStripMenuItem2)
            {
             //letterLogToolStripMenuItem2 clicked
            }
        }
```

Comment: what if the first two methods are in a different class than the second two?

Comment: Which two methods exactly? Clicks? If so, you can still add a new event handler.